# Simple Script - Export Groups and nested Objects into file (dynamic)

Tags: powershell

I'm quite new to powershell and I'm trying to create a simple script, that exports groups and underlying objects to a csv file. It all works fine if I would access the data staticly, by for example indexing the values from the array but how can I change all that, to be dynamic?

```
$Groups = Get-QADGroup 
$Result = @()
$Groups | ForEach-Object {
    $Group = $_
    $Members = Get-QADGroupMember $Group -Indirect
    $Obj = '' | Select-Object -Property Name, Members #, members2 
    $Obj.Name = $Group.Name
    #$Obj.Members = $Members[0].Name     ----would work, but should be dynamic
    #$Obj.members2 = $Members[1].Name    ----would work, but should be dynamic
    $Result += $Obj
}
$Result | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\groups.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode -Delimiter ";"
```

So that I just can write something like `$Obj.Members = $Members` but this doesn't work and gives me this output:

```
"Name";"Members"
"RootGroup01";"System.Object[]"
"RootGroup02";"System.Object[]"
"RootGroup03";"System.Object[]"
```

But I'd like something like this (example data):

```
"Name";"Members"
"RootGroup01";"Subuser01";"Subuser02";"SubGroup01"
"RootGroup02";"SubGroup02"
"RootGroup03";"SubGroup03";"Subuser02";"Subuser03";"Subuser04"; 
...
```

All the subgroups/subusers are in the `$Members` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there actually. All you need is to iterate `$Members` and select the property you need and (as @TheMadTechinian suggested) join the array:

```
$Obj.Members = ($Members | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name") -join ';'
```

Comment: He'll get the same result since it is  still a nested array.

Comment: Indeed. Forgot to join the array. ) Edited.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have implemented your line but it shows me `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.` error, I can't execute the script

Comment: Sorry, the opening parenthesis was in the wrong place. Fixed now.